# Apache Camel: create and return file in response on the fly

Tags: file, download, apache-camel, fileoutputstream, cxfrs

I have a Camel route that should return a file in the response, which is created based on the request data. While this works fine with the following (greatly simplified) route, the problem is that I need to first create an actual file on the server that I can then add to the exchange body.

As I don't want these file piling up on the disk, I would prefer to either not create them at all or delete them directly from the same route.

The only way around this I currently see is to have a regular cleanup job that deletes these temporary files.
Any suggestions on how to solve this in a better way?

```
from("cxfrs://...")
  .process(exchange -> {
    File file = new File("out.pdf");
    // write data to new FileOutputStream(file);
    exchange.getIn().setBody(file);
  })
```

The response content type is `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Have you tried simply returning an `OutputStream` instead, rather than using files?

Comment: I have tried that, but Camel seems unable to handle OutputStreams: "No message body writer has been found"

Comment: Sorry, I meant to point to the jax-rs class `StreamingOutput` https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html